# Change row values while having privileges for only one column in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

The table table1 has 3 columns.

```
id  column1 column2
1   a       a
2   a       a
```

I have select/update privileges only for id column.

How could I change values in row with id 2, so it looks this way.

```
2   b   b
```

If I had update permissions for all columns, I could do this.

```
update table1
set column1 = value, column2 = value
where id = 2;
```

I don't, so I could probably delete row 2 and then insert the values I want, but is there a way to do it without deleting?

Comment: If you want to change the data, you need update permissions.  Get the permissions you need to do your job.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @Ersin There is no error. I'm just looking for another way to do it. Out of curiosity.

Comment: @Gor Imagine that I can't do it for reasons that go beyond common sense and mortal comprehension. Is there a way in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could update columns (tables, objects, whatever) to which you don't have permission, then the database is not doing its job.

You always have the option of creating a procedure in the owning schema:

```
PROCEDURE ownerschema.updatetable1 (
    p_id           IN table1.id%TYPE
  , p_newcolumn1   IN table1.column1%TYPE
  , p_newcolumn2   IN table1.column2%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE table1
       SET column1 = p_newcolumn1, column2 = p_newcolumn2
     WHERE id = p_id;
END updatetable1;
```